# Are SharePoint 2007 WSP solutions fully compatible in 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, solution-package

I would like to know if SharePoint 2007 .WSP solutions are fully compatible to be deployed in SharePoint 2010.

Or what are the factors that I should consider in proceeding with the above plan.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio 2010 the Import SharePoint Solution Package project allows you to import a WSP, and create a SharePoint 2010 solution project.

Here some links may help you:

[Upgrading SharePoint 2007 Projects to SharePoint 2010](http://geekswithblogs.net/juanlarios/archive/2011/03/29/upgrading-sharepoint-2007-projects-to-sharepoint-2010.aspx)

[Updating a SharePoint 2007 WSP in Visual Studio 2010](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jorman/archive/2010/09/09/updating-a-sharepoint-2007-wsp-in-visual-studio-2010.aspx)